# Manejo de Session en Angular o Java

Tags: java, angular, session

Estoy desarrollando por primera ves una aplicativo web en angular que va usar un api que tengo en java,mi pregunta es si la session del usuario que se logea (ingresa al sistema) esa session al validar usuario correcto la debo crear en java en su backend o en el service de angular.

Comment: @BetaM No es una opinion ni consejo es una pregunta sobre algo que estoy aprendiendo y creo que cuando no sabias desarrollo aclarabas tus dudas con alguien o no sabias como hacerlo y pedias ayuda para desarrollar un buen código ya qeu tam bien pasaste por dudas como las mias.

Comment: Exacto pero la respuesta se basará en las opiniones de cada usuario, por eso lo comento, igual puedes tratar en el [chat]

Comment: Una forma correcta y segura de realizar la integración seria: Al ingresar usuario y contraseña estas se validan contra un servicio de la API (JAVA), si todo es correcto retornas un token de transacción JWT(JsonWebToken) este token se valida en cada transacción a la API y tiene un tiempo de vida, mientras el usuario Angular tiene una sesión web para mantener el token y verificar la inactividad en caso se deba cerrar la sesión si es necesario, en general para la API no se debe de guardar ningún estado del cliente porque eso evita que la API pueda escalar fácilmente.

Comment: La API solo se encarga de validar y servir la información solicitada y el manejo de estado solo es necesario en situaciones muy concretas y avanzadas que requieres estrategias para compartir el estado entre los servidores que manejan la réplica de la API .